# jHipster spinner loading css cancelled by browser

Tags: angular, jhipster

I've generated a JHipster project and I have put a gif in my index.html as a spinner loading.

Everything is fine with this spinner when I get to the main path of a component (let say for example localhost:9000/dossiers/detail), but when I want to access another page of the same component with the same URL but with parameters (e.g: localhost:9000/dossiers/detail?affCode=abc) the spinner do show but the css is cancelled by browser. So, the spinner appears at the left top corner of the page instead of being in the middle.

Is it a way to solve this? I saw the "cancelled" thing happens when the browser encounters iframe issues. Would it be related to the URL with params?

To link different pages to the same component I use the routes, that it what is used by JHipster when generating the entities page, for example:

```
export const recordsRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: RecordsComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: [Authority.USER],
    defaultSort: 'affCode,asc',
    pageTitle: 'records.title',
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService],
},
{
  path: 'detail',
  component: DetailledRecordComponent,
  resolve: {
    recordDetailQuotes: RecordDetailResolve,
},
data: {
  authorities: [Authority.USER],
  pageTitle: 'detailledRecord.title',
},
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService],
},
```

[image: css cancelled by browser]
[image: spinner without css]

Comment: What is the use of this spinner? Is it global? For route transitions? Why putting the spinner in index.html, don't you think it would better encapsulated within an angular component that could listen to events show/hide?

Comment: It is global. When generating the project with JHipster the spinner is by default put in the index.html. It shows when the page of the component called is not fully loaded. I don't think that encapsulate it in another component is a good idea since the purpose of it is to be shown before the component page called is loaded.

Comment: Oh this one, so it's more a splash screen, then you're right it must be in index.html before the angular app has loaded. So what did you change exactly? Only the image? What makes you think it's related to an iframe? Have you tested it in a prod build  (without using npm start), it could make a difference.

Comment: You're right I'd better call it splash screen. I only changed the image, indeed. It is easily reproductible with any JHipster project with the entities pages for example. I don't think it is related to an iframe but it seems that the browser handle it like so due to the message I get in the console. Same problem in prod environment.

Comment: If it's reproducible with unmodified generated project then you should report it on github. Maybe it's due to the Content Security Policy in SecurityConfiguration.java which is too strict for this deep linking case.

Comment: I've generated a brand new project, created an entity "record" with a "name" field. On every page I have the pacman splash screen, except when I go to path with parameters (ex: "http://localhost:9000/record/1/view"). I have a white screen because the loading.css is canceled, like in my project. I'll open an issue on Github, thank you.

Comment: This is well described, it will be a good report, don't forget to include the  output of `jhipster info` of your test  project, it includes everything that is required to reproduce (even though it's fairly obvious here)